# How can I auto calculate (first input) and (second input) etc.... and after calculation process sum all input in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

```
let button = document.querySelector(".btn");
let buttonReset = document.querySelector(".reset");
let buttonCalulate = document.querySelector(".calculate");


button.addEventListener("click",function(){
  const quantity = parseInt(document.querySelector("#myNumber").value);  //Declare input
  if(quantity >= 0) {

      for (var i=1; quantity>=i ; i++){

    let length = "<p class='first'>"+ i +". Length : <input type='number' class='second"+i+"' value='' /> </p>";
    let height = "<p class='first'> Height : <input type='number' class='second"+i+"' value='' /> </p>";
    let width =  "<p class='first'> Width : <input type='number' class='second"+i+"' value='' /> </p>";
    let boxQuantity =  "<p class='first'> Total Box : <input type='number' class='second"+i+"' value='' /> </p>";
    let inputTotal = length + height + width + boxQuantity ;
    
    document.querySelector(".calBox").innerHTML += inputTotal;
    }
    document.querySelector(".resetDiv").style.display = "flex";
    button.disabled=true;
  }
  
});

  buttonReset.addEventListener("click", function(){
    location.reload(true);
  });



  buttonCalulate.addEventListener("click", function(){
    let calQuantity = parseInt(document.querySelector("#myNumber").value);  
  if (calQuantity >0 ){
    
    for (var i=1; calQuantity>=i ; i++){
      

      let calLength = parseInt(document.querySelectorAll(".second"+i)[0].value);
      let calHeight = parseInt(document.querySelectorAll(".second"+i)[1].value);
      let calWidth =  parseInt(document.querySelectorAll(".second"+i)[2].value);
      let calBoxQuantity =  parseInt(document.querySelectorAll(".second"+i)[3].value);
      var calFirstStep = (calLength * calHeight * calWidth ) * calBoxQuantity;
      var calVolumeResult = calFirstStep / 6000; 
    }
    document.querySelector(".volumeResult").innerHTML = "Volume Weight : "+calVolumeResult+"kg";
    let cbmVolume = calVolumeResult * 0.006;
    document.querySelector(".cbmVolume").innerHTML = "CBM : " + cbmVolume;

  }

});
```

that is my js code problem is only last value out !   my plan are first ask cargo box , then to calculate different cargo box size will appear quantity of box after that auto start calculation (LxWxH)/6000 and ((LxWxH)/6000 ) *0.006 , and then all will sum first calculation, second calculation and etc.... after that final result will out .

`let calLength = parseInt(document.querySelectorAll(".second1")[0].value);`

`let calHeight = parseInt(document.querySelectorAll(".second1")[1].value);`

`let calWidth =  parseInt(document.querySelectorAll(".second1")[2].value);`

get total first calculation

`let calLength = parseInt(document.querySelectorAll(".second2")[0].value);`

`let calHeight = parseInt(document.querySelectorAll(".second2")[1].value);`

`let calWidth =  parseInt(document.querySelectorAll(".second2")[2].value);`   get total second calculation etc... and sum all calculation .

problem are we can't know how many user box will input it can be 10 input form or 20 may be so  so can't make variable to fix  it will change as user input request.

If you want to know all about my code i can upload all index cause I'm still learning can can't figure out how to do solve . Should I create an array for that or what can I do other?

[image]

I was try to make an array to sum all and
look for auto create variable for each But failed that's why i'm here

Comment: Click [edit], then click the `[<>]`  shaped snippet editor. Cut and paste your script and add RELEVANT rendered HTML and CSS and if needed, frameworks to make a [mcve].
Hint: Delegate the event listeners to the closest common container. Then wrap the Ps in a div with class="fields" and use `document.querySelectorAll("#container .fields")` to  get all SETS of fields. Change the classes from second to "height", "width" etc and navigate them using the parentDiv. Make a better example and I will look sometime later

Answer (score 0):

Enjoy.

```
<div id="example_container">
  <label>
    <span>Enter the total number of cargo spaces:</span>
    <input class="total_spaces" type="number">
  </label>
  <button class="total_spaces">OK</button>
  
  <div class="all_fields hide">
    <div class="cargo_row_template flex">
      <span class="row_number"></span>
      <span class="txt">Length</span>
      <input class="length" type="number">
      <span class="txt">Height</span>
      <input class="height" type="number">
      <span class="txt">Width</span>
      <input class="width" type="number">
      <span class="txt no-wrap">Total Boxes:</span>
      <input class="total_boxes" type="number">
    </div>  
  </div>
  
  <div class="flex">
    <button class="calculate">Calculate</button>
  </div>
  
</div>

// wait for dom to be built before running this javascript
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    
  const updateCalculations = () => {
    const all_cargo_rows = document.querySelectorAll('.cargo_row_template');
    const totals = [...all_cargo_rows].map(($cargo_row) => {
        // get numerical value of each field (if blank then use 0)
        const length = Number($cargo_row.querySelector("input.length").value) || 0;
      const height = Number($cargo_row.querySelector("input.height").value) || 0;
        const width = Number($cargo_row.querySelector("input.width").value) || 0;
      const total_boxes = Number($cargo_row.querySelector("input.total_boxes").value) || 0;
      console.log(length, height, width, total_boxes);

            return (length*width*height)/6000;
    });
    console.log(totals);
  }

  const createFields = (num_of_fields) => {
    const $cargo_row_template = document.querySelector('.cargo_row_template');
    const $all_fields = document.querySelector('.all_fields');
    
    // clear out all rows (if any)
    emptyDiv($all_fields);
    
    // create a clone for each cargo space needed to be built.
    const new_fields = Array.from({length: num_of_fields}, (_, i) => {
        // clones row
      const $clone = $cargo_row_template.cloneNode(true);
      $clone.querySelector('.row_number').textContent = `${i+1}.`;
      return $clone;
    });
    $cargo_row_template.remove();
    $all_fields.append(...new_fields);
    $all_fields.classList.remove('hide');
  }

    const initEventListeners = () => {
    const $total_spaces_btn = document.querySelector('button.total_spaces');
    $total_spaces_btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      const $total_spaces = document.querySelector('input.total_spaces');
      createFields($total_spaces.value);
    });
    const $calculate = document.querySelector("button.calculate");
    $calculate.addEventListener('click', () => {
        updateCalculations();
    })
  }
  
  const emptyDiv = ($element) => {
    // removes all elements within a div
    while ($element.firstChild) $element.firstChild.remove();
  }
  
  const init = () => {
    // attach all initial event listeners
    initEventListeners();
  }

    // start program
    init();
  
  // NOTE I use $ for DOM elements, camelCase for function names and snake_case for variable names
});

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.no-wrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/q3h05u8e/2/